# inspect.getmembers() vs __dict__.items() vs dir()

Tags: python, namespaces

Can anybody explain to me with adequate examples whats the difference b/w

```
>>> import inspect
>>> inspect.getmembers(1)
```

and

```
>>> type(1).__dict__.items()
```

and

```
>>> dir(1)
```

except that they show an decreasing no.s of attributes & methods in that order.
1 is integer (but it can be of any type.)

---

**EDIT**

```
>>>obj.__class__.__name__  #gives the class name of object  
>>>dir(obj)                #gives attributes & methods  
>>>dir()                   #gives current scope/namespace
>>>obj.__dict__            #gives attributes
```

Comment: Depending on your purpose, you may want to edit the last block again, replacing `object` for sth else (say, obj) and change the last comment from "gives attributes" to sth like "gives the _instance_ attributes" -- as when `dir(obj)` basically "includes inheritance", `obj.__dict__.keys()` does not

Answer (score 25, accepted):

`dir()` allows you to customize what attributes your object reports, by defining `__dir__()`.

From the manual, if `__dir__()` is not defined:

> If the object is a module object, the list contains the names of the module’s attributes.
>
> If the object is a type or class object, the list contains the names of its attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its bases.
>
> Otherwise, the list contains the object’s attributes’ names, the names of its class’s attributes, and recursively of the attributes of its class’s base classes.

This is also what `inspect.getmembers()` returns, except it returns tuples of `(name, attribute)` instead of just the names.

`object.__dict__` is a dictionary of the form `{key: attribute, key2: atrribute2}` etc.

`object.__dict__.keys()` has what the other two are lacking.

From the docs on `inspect.getmembers()`:

> getmembers() does not return metaclass attributes when the argument is a class (this behavior is inherited from the dir() function).

For `int.__dict__.keys()`, this is

```
['__setattr__', '__reduce_ex__', '__reduce__', '__class__', '__delattr__', '__subclasshook__', '__sizeof__', '__init__']
```

To summarize, `dir()` and `inspect.getmembers()` are basically the same, while `__dict__` is the complete namespace including metaclass attributes.