# Why does cls.__name__ not appear in dir()?

Tags: python

Let's say I have a simple class:

```
class Foobar(object):
    pass
```

If I use `dir(Foobar)`, I'll get the following output:

```
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', '__weakref__']
```

Even though it does not appear in the output of `dir()`, I can access `__name__`:

```
Foobar.__name__
```

and get `Foobar`.

Why does Python behave that way?

Comment: See [`inspect.getmembers()` vs `__dict__.items()` vs `dir()`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761106/inspect-getmembers-vs-dict-items-vs-dir) for some general info about `dir` and related functions.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`dir` is not guaranteed to return all possible attributes. From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#dir):

> Because dir() is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an
>   interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names
>   more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set
>   of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For
>   example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the
>   argument is a class.

Answer (score 6):

Answers on a recent dupe of this question have lead me to want to elaborate on this answer a little bit more.  First, the accepted answer is correct.  `dir` simply calls the `__dir__` hook method and the default `__dir__` hook method usually just returns the keys of the object's `__dict__`.

Second, `__name__` isn't in `object.__dict__` and it doesn't get put in the `__dict__` of subclasses either.  If it isn't in `__dict__`, where is it and how does it get looked up?

As I understand [the source code](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L861), there are a number of descriptors which are set by `type` during class creation.  One of these descriptors is `__name__`.  The `__name__` getter calls [type_name](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L390) and the setter calls [type_set_name](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L424).  These getters/setters actually get/set the name in the `tp_name` slot of the type object instance (i.e. the class).  Since this is actually a special slot on the type object, it doesn't actually live in the class `__dict__` and therefore it doesn't get reported by `vars` or `dir`.

Note that `dir` for type object instances (i.e. classes) specifically does not add members from the from the `__class__` attribute because ["methods belonging to the metaclass would probably be more confusing than helpful"](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/master/Objects/typeobject.c#L3293).

So, let's put this all together.

- `object` doesn't have a `__name__` attribute but `type` does.
- `type`'s `__name__` attribute is actually a descriptor.
- Since `object`'s metaclass is `type`, when `object.__name__` is requested, `type`'s `__name__` descriptor is invoked.
- The `name` descriptor looks up the name in the `type->tp_name` slot.  The `type->tp_name` slot is populated by `type.__new__` when the class is created.
- `object.__dir__` is specifically written to *not* report properties on the class's metaclass since the python devs believe that would do more harm than good.

Answer (score 3):

According to the python documentation about the [dir() method](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html?highlight=dir#dir), you can implement a __dir__() method on your object that returns the list of the items you want to see when calling a dir on your object.

The __name__ member is part of some [special attributes](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=__name__#special-attributes) of python objects, and as says the documentation :

> Some of these are not reported by the dir() built-in function.

Answer (score 0):

I've encountered this problem when writing pytests. Although, people explain why, no work-around was suggested. The only work-around I found was to move .py files to another directory and then import them.