# what's the difference between dir(self) and self.__dict__

Tags: python, class

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [inspect.getmembers() vs __dict__.items() vs dir()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761106/inspect-getmembers-vs-dict-items-vs-dir)

```
class Base():
    def __init__(self, conf):
        self.__conf__ = conf
        for i in self.__dict__:
            print i,"dict"
        for i in dir(self):
            print i,"dir"

class Test(Base):
      a = 1
      b = 2

t = Test("conf")
```

The output is:

```
__conf__ dict
__conf__ dir
__doc__ dir
__init__ dir
__module__ dir
a dir
b dir
```

Can anyone explain a little bit about this?

Comment: I'm not sure how you're getting that output. Where is the `dict` and `dir` coming from?

Comment: @kindall I just fixed the code,  `print i,"dict"` and `print i, "dir"`

Comment: As far as I know, `__conf__` has no special meaning in python.  You shouldn't use variable (or attribute) names `__something__` unless you're using it for the special meaning assigned by the python standard because those variables are *reserved* for future versions of python.

Comment: another useful function in the family is `vars`. When faced with a `class` I haven't seen before, I use both `dir(t)` and `vars(t)` to sound it out.

Comment: Please [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=[python]+%2Bdir+%2B__dict__+%2Bdifference&submit=search) before asking

Answer (score 9, accepted):

An object's `__dict__` stores the attributes of the instance. The only attribute of your instance is `__conf__` since it's the only one set in your `__init__()` method. `dir()` returns a list of names of "interesting" attributes of the instance, its class, and its parent classes. These include `a` and `b` from your `Test` class and `__init__` from your `Base` class, plus a few other attributes Python adds automatically.

Class attributes are stored in each class's `__dict__`, so what `dir()` is doing is walking the inheritance hierarchy and collecting information from each class.

Comment: Good answer, especially the first part. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361256/whats-the-biggest-difference-between-dir-and-dict-in-python/14361362#14361362) for a detailed explanation of the "interesting attributes of the instance".