# What's the biggest difference between dir() and __dict__ in Python

Tags: python, introspection

```
class C(object):
    def f(self):
        print self.__dict__
        print dir(self)
c = C()
c.f()
```

output:

```
{}

['__class__', '__delattr__','f',....]
```

why there is not a 'f' in self.__dict__

Answer (score 161, accepted):

### `dir()` does much more than look up `__dict__`

First of all, `dir()` is a API method that knows how to use attributes like `__dict__` to look up attributes of an object.

Not all objects have a `__dict__` attribute though. For example, if you were to add a [`__slots__` attribute](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/datamodel.html#slots) to your custom class, instances of that class won't have a `__dict__` attribute, yet `dir()` can still list the available attributes on those instances:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     __slots__ = ('bar',)
...     bar = 'spam'
... 
>>> Foo().__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute '__dict__'
>>> dir(Foo())
['__class__', '__delattr__', '__doc__', '__format__', '__getattribute__', '__hash__', '__init__', '__module__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__slots__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'bar']
```

The same applies to many built-in types; `list`s do not have a `__dict__` attribute, but you can still list all the attributes using `dir()`:

```
>>> [].__dict__
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute '__dict__'
>>> dir([])
['__add__', '__class__', '__contains__', '__delattr__', '__delitem__', '__delslice__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__getitem__', '__getslice__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__iadd__', '__imul__', '__init__', '__iter__', '__le__', '__len__', '__lt__', '__mul__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__reversed__', '__rmul__', '__setattr__', '__setitem__', '__setslice__', '__sizeof__', '__str__', '__subclasshook__', 'append', 'count', 'extend', 'index', 'insert', 'pop', 'remove', 'reverse', 'sort']
```

### What `dir()` does with instances

Python instances have their own `__dict__`, but so does their class:

```
>>> class Foo(object):
...     bar = 'spam'
... 
>>> Foo().__dict__
{}
>>> Foo.__dict__.items()
[('__dict__', <attribute '__dict__' of 'Foo' objects>), ('__weakref__', <attribute '__weakref__' of 'Foo' objects>), ('__module__', '__main__'), ('bar', 'spam'), ('__doc__', None)]
```

The `dir()` method uses *both* these `__dict__` attributes, *and* the one on `object` to create a complete list of available attributes on the instance, the class, and on all ancestors of the class.

When you set attributes on a class, instances see these too:

```
>>> f = Foo()
>>> f.ham
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'Foo' object has no attribute 'ham'
>>> Foo.ham = 'eggs'
>>> f.ham
'eggs'
```

because the attribute is added to the class `__dict__`:

```
>>> Foo.__dict__['ham']
'eggs'
>>> f.__dict__
{}
```

Note how the instance `__dict__` is left empty. Attribute lookup on Python objects follows the hierarchy of objects from instance to type to parent classes to search for attributes.

Only when you set attributes directly on the instance, will you see the attribute reflected in the `__dict__` of the instance, while the class `__dict__` is left unchanged:

```
>>> f.stack = 'overflow'
>>> f.__dict__
{'stack': 'overflow'}
>>> 'stack' in Foo.__dict__
False
```

### TLDR; or the summary

`dir()` doesn't just look up an object's `__dict__` (which sometimes doesn't even exist), it will use the object's heritage (its class or type, and any superclasses, or parents, of that class or type) to give you a complete picture of all available attributes.

An instance `__dict__` is just the 'local' set of attributes on that instance, and does not contain every attribute available on the instance. Instead, you need to look at the class and the class's inheritance tree too.

Comment: `dir` will also look at `__dir__` if implemented, which can return strings for things that aren't even implemented as formal properties or attributes, but are simply lazily-implemented in `__getattr__`, for instance.

Comment: @PaulMcGuire: I didn't want to go into too much detail as to what `dir()` does; it's a long answer as it is, and I didn't need to include that detail to get the point across. :-)

Comment: See [what's the difference between `dir(self)` and `self.__dict__`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13302917/whats-the-difference-between-dirself-and-self-dict/13302981#13302981) for a more concise answer.

Comment: When I use dir on an object that has `@Property` getter / setter decorators, it returns that "public" name of the property (I realise these leading underscores are just naming conventions and not real access modifiers) . When I use `__dict__` it returns only the private attributes e.g. this DatasourceItem object has properties like `id` which `dir` will return, but `__dict__` returns `_id`  https://github.com/tableau/server-client-python/blob/master/tableauserverclient/models/datasource_item.py

Comment: @Davos: A `property` object is a descriptor object that lives on the class, not on the instance. What a property getter or setter or deleter does is *entirely implementation dependent*. A property can do anything it pleases, it doesn't have to do anything with the instance at all. `dir()` on an instance will still list any attributes on the class *and* any attributes in the instance `__dict__`, so `dir()` on a `DatasourceItem` instance will show both the `connections` property defined on the class, and the `_connections` attribute on the instance.

Comment: @Davos: so yes, that's entirely expected. The `DatasourceItem.id` `property` object lives on the class, not on the instance. `instance.id` will trigger the getter method, which then returns `self._id`, where `self._id` is an attribute on the instance.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, that does clear things up for me. I was attempting to retrieve an existing datasource object, use most of its attributes in a new object instance and then pass that back to the server to overwrite. I thought perhaps fetching the attributes as a dictionary would be a bit more dynamic, but just fetching the attribute values with dot notation is probably better in terms of "coding to the interface", and there's only a few non-defaults. I was being lazy and trying to automate something that needn't be.

Answer (score 6):

The function `f` belongs to the dictionary of class `C`.  `c.__dict__` yields attributes specific to the instance `c`.

```
>>> class C(object):
    def f(self):
        print self.__dict__


>>> c = C()
>>> c.__dict__
{}
>>> c.a = 1
>>> c.__dict__
{'a': 1}
```

`C.__dict__` would yield attributes of class `C`, including function `f`.

```
>>> C.__dict__
dict_proxy({'__dict__': <attribute '__dict__' of 'C' objects>, '__module__': '__main__', '__weakref__': <attribute '__weakref__' of 'C' objects>, '__doc__': None, 'f': <function f at 0x0313C1F0>})
```

While an object can refer to an attribute of its class (and indeed all the ancestor classes), the class attribute so referred does not become part of the associated **dict** itself.  Thus while it is legitimate access to function `f` defined in class `C` as `c.f()`, it does not appear as an attribute of `c` in `c.__dict__`.

```
>>> c.a = 1
>>> c.__dict__
{'a': 1}
```

Answer (score 3):

Class `dir()` and `__dict__` only show defined functions (methods).
Instance `dir()` shows data+methods while its `__dict__` only shows
data attributes, not methods.

```py
class C2:
...     def __init__(self, id): 
...         self.id = id
...     def set(self, len):
...         self.len = len        
...         
c2 = C2("stick")
dir(C2)
['__class__',.., '__init__', 'set']
dir(c2)
['__class__',.., '__init__', 'id', 'set']
C2.__dict__
mappingproxy({'__init__': <function C2.__init__ at 0x000001899C61E9D0>, 'set': <function C2.set at 0x000001899C61ED30>,...})
c2.__dict__
{'id': 'stick'}
```