# How to get the names of attributes when classes in Python use __slots__?

Tags: python, inheritance, reflection, slots

When I define a new-style class in Python, I can get the defined attributes (names and values) by using the `__dict__`-Attribute, that contains a dictionary of the things.

I'd like to use slots in my classes and their subclasses, because I will created hundreds of thousands of instances and want to save some memory. However, classes that do use `__slots__` will not have a `__dict__`-Attribute so I can not reflectively access their values that way.

Is there another way, preferable one that preserves the order of the attributes defined for such a class?

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Note that because `__dict__` is a dictionary, there is no defined order for the attributes you list.

Comment: Related: [what's the biggest difference between dir and \_\_dict__ in python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/14361256)

Comment: @MartijnPieters and I'll be bookmarking that for future linking use, great answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should use the [`dir()` built-in function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir) to list members of objects instead accessing of either `__dict__` or `__slots__` directly.

An instance `__dict__` will only list attributes set directly on the instance, while `dir()` will list attributes (including methods) on the class and bases of that class as well. It'll also list anything defined as a slot.

You can use the [`inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/2/library/inspect.html) to help you filter the output of `dir()`; if you are not interested in methods for example the `inspect.ismethod()` can help.

Comment: +1. Depending on what is being done, [the `inspect` module](http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/inspect.html) might also be worth a look.