# __dict__.items() not returning all object attributes

Tags: python, oop, attributes, beautifulsoup

Consider:

```
>>> result = requests.get('http://dotancohen.com')
>>> soup = BeautifulSoup(result.text)
>>> a = soup.find('a')
>>> for k,v in a.__dict__.items():
...     print(str(k)+": "+str(v))
... 
can_be_empty_element: False
previous_element: <h1><a class="title" href="/">Dotan Cohen</a></h1>
next_sibling: None
name: a
parent: <h1><a class="title" href="/">Dotan Cohen</a></h1>
namespace: None
prefix: None
previous_sibling: None
attrs: {'href': '/', 'class': ['title']}
next_element: Dotan Cohen
parser_class: <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>
hidden: False
contents: ['Dotan Cohen']
>>> pprint(a)
<a class="title" href="/">Dotan Cohen</a>
>>>
```

The value that `pprint` returns is not the value of any of the attributes that `__dict__.items()` returns. That means to me that there exist attributes of `a` that are not returned in `__dict__.items()`. How might I access those attributes?

Comment: Why are you assuming the `str()` representation should match the instance attributes? `attrs` is there, as well as `contents` and `name`, so everything you see in the string representation can be found in the instance attributes as well.

Comment: @MartijnPieters: `repr` rather than `str`, but your point stands!

Comment: @MartijnPieters: I agree that everything seen in the string representation can be found in the instance attributes. However notice that the information is in the attributes `previous_element` and `parent`. The actual content of the tag itself is not shown. However, it must be stored _somewhere_ as `pprint()` finds it! So why isn't it returned in `__dict__.items()`?

Comment: Yes, it is shown; the contents of the tag is `Dotan Cohen` and is in the `.contents` attribute. The `parent` and `previous_element` tags are representations of *those* elements, so shown as HTML strings as well.

Comment: Why the downvote? How could I improve the question?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are no attributes missing in the instance dictionary. Let's take a look at the representation of the element:

```
<a class="title" href="/">Dotan Cohen</a>
```

We have a tag name (`a`), attributes (`title` and `href`, with values) and we have textual content (`Dotan Cohen`). These are *all* present in the instance attributes you listed:

- `name: a`
- `attrs: {'href': '/', 'class': ['title']}`
- `contents: ['Dotan Cohen']`

`contents` is a list of direct descendants of this element; there is only one, a text object (`NavigableString` instances use a representation that looks just like a regular string).

You could use the [`vars()` built-in API function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#vars) to list instance attributes. I see you are using `pprint()` already; rather than loop over `.items()`, just use `pprint(vars(a))` and save yourself typing a full loop; as a bonus `pprint()` sorts the keys first:

```
>>> pprint(vars(a))
{'attrs': {'class': ['title'], 'href': '/'},
 'can_be_empty_element': False,
 'contents': [u'Dotan Cohen'],
 'hidden': False,
 'name': 'a',
 'namespace': None,
 'next_element': u'Dotan Cohen',
 'next_sibling': None,
 'parent': <h1><a class="title" href="/">Dotan Cohen</a></h1>,
 'parser_class': <class 'bs4.BeautifulSoup'>,
 'prefix': None,
 'previous_element': <h1><a class="title" href="/">Dotan Cohen</a></h1>,
 'previous_sibling': None}
```

The string you are looking at is built by the `.__repr__()` hook of the element class:

```
>>> a.__repr__()
'<a class="title" href="/">Dotan Cohen</a>'
```

which normally is called when `repr()` is used on an object:

```
>>> repr(a)
'<a class="title" href="/">Dotan Cohen</a>'
```

The string is built up from the parsed element information you see in the objects attributes.

Comment: From what I understand by your explanation, the actual returned value for the tag is not stored anywhere? That means that the value returned by `pprint()` must be made by some sort of `ToString()` method? I can confirm by looking at the source code of the website parsed that the order of the attributes in the HTML are not the same order as the attributes in the string returned by `pprint()`.

Comment: Yes, you are looking at the `repr()` result of the object. The `__repr__` method takes care of building this from the attribute data. HTML attributes are not ordered (like Python dictionaries).

Comment: I see, thank you Martijn. From googling a bit I see that there exists a `dir()` method that will return all the 'names' of `a`, one of which is `__repr__`. `a.__repr__` does return `<bound method Tag.__unicode__ of <a class="title" href="/">Dotan Cohen</a>>`. However, I am having a hard time finding a definition for the word 'names' other than "names are: variables, modules, functions, etc.".

Comment: @dotancohen: see [what's the biggest difference between dir and \_\_dict\_\_ in python](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14361362)