# where does python store inheritance information in a class?

Tags: python, oop, inheritance

python version `3.5.2`
I tried to get parent class from a child class:

```
class A:
    pass
class B(A):
    pass
```

after a little research, I got a solution from [python doc](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#class.__bases__): use `__base__`. (a special class attribute)
But I couldn't find **this `"__base__"`** in `B.__dict__` or `dir(B)`, which are my normal ways of getting attributes.

This is definitely class related information, if it's not in `B.__dict__` where is it? (although I realized that `"__base__"` is returned by `type(B).__dict__`)
And why isn't `dir()` returning it? based on [this stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361256/whats-the-biggest-difference-between-dir-and-dict-in-python) I read, `dir()` has some logics behind and it is supposed to return "a complete picture of all available attributes."

I initally thought this is hiding on purpose...but you can still easily manipulate a child's parent:

```
class C:
    pass
B.__bases__ = (C,) # voila, B got a new Dad
```

Answer (score 1):

See the note on [`dir()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) (emphasis mine):

> Note: Because `dir()` is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. **For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class.**

`B` is a class, its metaclass is `type`. So if you really want the *full* picture, you should also look as the metaclass’ `dir()`:

```
>>> B.__class__ is type
True
>>> dir(type)
['__abstractmethods__', '__base__', '__bases__', '__basicsize__', '__call__', '__class__',
 '__delattr__', '__dict__', '__dictoffset__', '__dir__', '__doc__', '__eq__', '__flags__',
 '__format__', '__ge__', '__getattribute__', '__gt__', '__hash__', '__init__',
 '__init_subclass__', '__instancecheck__', '__itemsize__', '__le__', '__lt__',
 '__module__', '__mro__', '__name__', '__ne__', '__new__', '__prepare__', '__qualname__',
 '__reduce__', '__reduce_ex__', '__repr__', '__setattr__', '__sizeof__', '__str__',
 '__subclasscheck__', '__subclasses__', '__subclasshook__', '__text_signature__',
 '__weakrefoffset__', 'mro']
```

And there you have `__base__` and `__bases__`, and also those other things that appeared in [the list you linked](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#special-attributes), like `mro` and `__subclasses__`.

Comment: when I read that document, I thought `type(A).__dict__` to `A.__dict__` is like class attributes to instance attributes. so I said to myself, even though `type(A).__dict__` has `__bases__` does not mean `A.__dict__` has as well. You know, like **static** var vs **instance** var....now I realized that `type(type(A)) == type(A)` they are both classes, so `A.__dict__ >= type(A).__dict__`. but thanks for the answer