# Why isn't there __dict__ in dir("an imported module") as an attribute?

Tags: python

In Python, we are always told that `dir` lists any attribute of its questioned object. But why isn't there `__dict__` in `dir("an imported module")`?

Comment: Why would you expect that?

Comment: I think you're saying that you imported a module, and `dir(modulename)` doesn't include `__dict__`, but `modulename.__dict__` does seem to exist. It might make your question clearer if that was stated in your question instead of just being implicit.

Comment: Check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361256/whats-the-biggest-difference-between-dir-and-dict-in-python and look at my answer for some more information.

Comment: @toti08, I think  it would be great, if there was a tool that you could list quickly and easily all attributes of an object. I was thinking dir() or something has got this role.

Comment: @khelwood, you are right. your description is explicit and stated clearly the case.

Comment: Feel free to [edit] your question to make it clearer.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot rely on `dir([object])` returning accurate results. As stated [here](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#dir):

> If the object has a method named `__dir__()`, this method will be
>   called and must return the list of attributes. This allows objects
>   that implement a custom `__getattr__()` or `__getattribute__()`
>   function to customize the way `dir()` reports their attributes.
>
> If the object does not provide `__dir__()`, the function tries its
>   best to gather information from the object’s `__dict__` attribute, if
>   defined, and from its type object. The resulting list is not
>   necessarily complete, and may be inaccurate when the object has a
>   custom `__getattr__()`.

So try looking into the object you are trying to get the information from and look for the attributes yourself.

Answer (score 0):

The answer is in [python documentation for the `dir` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir):

> **Note:** Because `dir()` is supplied primarily as a convenience for use at an interactive prompt, it tries to supply an interesting set of names more than it tries to supply a rigorously or consistently defined set of names, and its detailed behavior may change across releases. For example, metaclass attributes are not in the result list when the argument is a class.

`__dict__` is a special attribute that is part of that exception.

Answer (score 0):

`dir()` doesn't just look up an object's `__dict__` (which sometimes doesn't even exist), it will use the object's heritage (its class or type, and any superclasses, or parents, of that class or type) to give you a complete picture of all available attributes.

An instance `__dict__` is just the 'local' set of attributes on that instance, and does not contain every attribute available on the instance. Instead, you need to look at the class and the class's inheritance tree too.

For more information, check out [the main differences between `dir()` and `__dict__`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14361256/whats-the-biggest-difference-between-dir-and-dict-in-python).