# What attributes does `__dict__` of a class or an instance contain, and what doesn't?

Tags: python, python-3.x

For the attributes of a class:

- The attribute `__dict__` of a class or an instance doesn't include `__base__`, `__name__`. 
  What attributes does `__dict__` of a class contain, and what doesn't?
- How can I get all the attributes of a class?

For the attributes of an instance:

- The attribute `__dict__` of   an instance doesn't include `__class__`.
  What attributes does `__dict__` of an instance contain, and what doesn't?
- How can I get all the attributes of an instance?

Thanks.

Comment: Look at the [`dir`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#dir) function. It includes parameters if super classes. More info [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6761106/inspect-getmembers-vs-dict-items-vs-dir)

Comment: It doesn't include most of the magic methods, anything defined in `__slots__`, among other things.

Comment: @MadPhysicist Thanks. What does "magic methods" mean?

Comment: @Ben. Anything starting and ending with double underscores: `__init__`, `__new__`, `__eq__`, etc. These methods serve a special purpose in Python, you should not make new ones up, and most of them are not set in `__dict__` as far as I am aware.

Comment: Also, you can have an infinite number of accessible attributes via `__getattr__` and `__getattribute__`, mostly the latter.

Answer (score 0):

`__dict__` excludes:

- Any attributes (or descriptors) defined on the type (or any type in the mro).
- Any attributes declared as part of a type implemented in C.
- Any attributes declared in `__slots__`.

The best you can do for listing all attributes is `dir`, but it is often unreliable.

Comment: There are also, ways to override `__dict__` itself, and ways to override the overriding. I forget how this works.

Answer (score -2):

**dict** is interesting. What you need to understand is how Python looks up attributes, methods, etc. Thing like **name** are stored in dir(instance), which is not part of the standard **getattr** of your class. Only explicitly defined attributes and methods are part of A.**dict**, the other stuff is part of a complex look-up system, the rest is looking at the class, at the subclasses, etc, until you get to 'object'.

Comment: Both second questions are not answered; and plz check the format `__dict__` vs __dict__